# Protect backend API to verify that API request coming from android app

Tags: android, .net

I have an android app which I distribute without google play store. I have a backend API in .NET

Now recently, I have noticed that many people are trying to access my API even the authenticated users are tracking and use it via postman and from their server.

I want to block all the trafic which are not coming from my android app.

Is there any possibility to do that?

I did study about the play integrity by firebase but for that they require to release app on play store. I can not release the app on play store due to some data concern.

I also explored auth0 but again any one can duplicate the code with same package name and URL.

I do not have any SSL on server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.